# How to correctly implement SNS receiver in Spring-cloud-aws framework? (i.e. @NotificationMessageMapping)

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, spring-cloud

I am currently using STS 3.6.3SR1 using Spring 4.1.4. Trying to test spring-cloud-aws for feasibility of use within our application.

**Jars Related to Question :**

spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure-1.0.0.RC2.jar

spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.0.RC2.jar

spring-cloud-aws-core-1.0.0.RC2.jar

spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.0.0.RC2.jar

**Using aws-sdk-1.9.3**

Currently have this in my xml context file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <ref bean="notificationResolver"/>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven> 

<aws-messaging:notification-argument-resolver id="notificationResolver" />


<aws-messaging:notification-messaging-template id="notificationMessagingTemplate" default-destination="snsChannelTopic"/>
```

Currently have this Controller class defined as my endpoint.

```
public class AmazonSNSController {
    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @NotificationSubscriptionMapping
    public void handleSubscriptionMessage(SnsHelper status) throws IOException {
        //We subscribe to start receive the message
        status.setRequest(request);
        status.setResponse(response);
        status.confirmSubscription();
    }

    @NotificationMessageMapping
    public void handleNotificationMessage(@NotificationSubject String subject, @NotificationMessage String message) {
        System.out.println(subject + message);
    }

    @NotificationUnsubscribeConfirmationMapping
    public void handleUnsubscribeMessage(SnsHelper status) {
        //e.g. the client has been unsubscribed and we want to "re-subscribe"
        //status.confirmSubscription();
    }
```

In the above class SnsHelper implements [NotificationStatus](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/endpoint/NotificationStatus.java) and I have confirmed the subscription properly. I am receiving notifications to the handleNotificationMessage method as well. However, both Strings evaluate to null regardless of what I send.

I believe this has to do with the *notificationResolver* not being registered/applied correctly.

Can anyone provide some guidance on this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your configuration seems to be good. Did you annotate your controller with @Controller and @RequestMapping? How do you send your SNS notifications? BTW, Spring Cloud 1.0.0.RELEASE is now available.

Comment: Yes I have annotated my controller with both Controller and RequestMapping. Since i was able to confirm subscription I do not think this is the issue. However, I was looking into the @EnableSns annotation and i see a method, 'addArgumentResolvers'. Is this required over and above registering my resolvers in the configuration?

Comment: I am sending my notifications through two ways during test. One is using the sendNotification command of the notificationMessaginTemplate, while the other is using the amazon console. However, in the future I will only be using the sendNotification command. Thanks for the info! Ill integrate 1.0.0 asap.

Comment: @EnableSns is the JavaConfig equivalent of what you have done in XML. If you have the possibility to debug I would recommend to put a breakpoint in org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.endpoint.AbstractNotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver#resolveArgument on line 49 and check what's in the _content_ map. If the subject and message is already empty in this map then the problems comes from the request itself. If it is not empty, you can step into the doResolverArgumentFromNotificationMessage method and check what happens in there.

Comment: HI @Alain I have not been able to set breakpoints in spring-cloud-aws code due to issues with linking the local xsd file + namespaces (not able to correctly configure spring.schemas+spring.handlers). However, I receive this warning in my context  : "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver.BEAN_NAME' not found [config set: acquisitionDbapis/
  web-context]- Referenced bean 'amazonSQSAsync' not found [config set: acquisitionDbapis/web-context]" where I am trying to configure my notificationMessagingTemplate. Any insight? Thanks.

Comment: For anyone reading this now, the solution is using either @EnableSns or importing SnsWebConfiguration to your configuration (if you are already creating an AmazonSNS bean). This will configure the correct argument resolvers